# How to display an image clicking on it using modal window on HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show an image when I click on it using a modal window, but, when I click on it doesn't display anything. The code is the following:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Seccion 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="seccion1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="./Seccion1/pueblodesal2.png" alt="Imagen central" class="center-image">
      <div class="image-grid">
        <img src="./Seccion1/1.jpg" alt="Imagen 1" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/1.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/2.jpg" alt="Imagen 2" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/2.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/3.jpg" alt="Imagen 3" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/3.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/4.jpg" alt="Imagen 4" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/4.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/5.jpg" alt="Imagen 5" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/5.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/6.jpg" alt="Imagen 6" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/6.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/7.jpg" alt="Imagen 7" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/7.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/8.jpg" alt="Imagen 8" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/8.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/9.jpg" alt="Imagen 9" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/9.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/10.jpg" alt="Imagen 10" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/10.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/11.jpg" alt="Imagen 11" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/11.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/12.jpg" alt="Imagen 12" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/12.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/13.jpg" alt="Imagen 13" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/13.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/14.jpg" alt="Imagen 14" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/14.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/15.jpg" alt="Imagen 15" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/15.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/16.jpg" alt="Imagen 16" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/16.jpg">
        <img src="./Seccion1/17.jpg" alt="Imagen 17" class="grid-image" data-src="./Seccion1/17.jpg">
      </div>
      
      <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="" alt="Modal image" class="modal-content">
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <script src="seccion1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-image");
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const modalContent = document.getElementById("modal-content");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");


images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    console.log(image.src)
    modalContent.src = image.src;
  });
});


closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});


window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

In the console I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (seccion1.js:11:22)
```

I try to debug the `image.src` and it gets the correct path. I'd like to know how to display the image using the `src` at class `modal-content`.

Comment: You should query your modal-content with `document.querySelector(".modal-content")` since you're using it as a class name not ID in your HTML

Comment: After the `images.forEach((image))` loop the reference to `image` as such no longer exists. You need to use the event `(current)target` `src` and assign *that* to the modal image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code, `modal-content` is a class, not an id, so when you call `getElementById`, that returns `null`. Just add an id to the `modal-content` element.

```
<img src="" alt="Modal image" class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `#modal-content` in html.

```html
<img src="" alt="Modal image" id="modal-content" class="modal-content">
```